# How do I log errors and warnings into a file?

Tags: php, error-handling

How do I turn on all error and warnings and log them to a file, but to set up all of that within the script (not changing anything in php.ini)?

I want to define a file name and so that all errors and warnings get logged into it.

Answer (score 421):

Use the following code:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
error_log( "Hello, errors!" );
```

Then watch the file:

```
tail -f /tmp/php-error.log
```

Or update `php.ini` as described in [this blog entry](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/01/30/advanced-php-error-handling-via-php/) from 2008.

Comment: `ini_set` does only work if that code is executed. Not useful for code that has *parse errors* because the error will be *before* the code is executed. Instead write those changes into the php.ini.

Comment: If you can't edit php.ini, you should be able to add this in the .htaccess : `php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log`. See http://perishablepress.com/how-to-enable-php-error-logging-via-htaccess/

Comment: I have  a question, how to get the error.log file to get created in my htdocs folder instead?

Comment: I guess you just change the folder from `tmp/php-error.log` to which ever location you desire?

Comment: This crashes my PHP in 5.4.0

Comment: @Tommy, So what was the error? Does changing the value of `error_log` work?

Comment: Could you explain `tail` is that linux command line tail recursion or windows?

Comment: @KolobCanyon Tail is a Linux command (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)

Answer (score 108):

See

- [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) — Send an error message somewhere

Example

```
error_log("You messed up!", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
```

You can [customize error handling with your own error handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to call this function for you whenever an error or warning or whatever you need to log occurs.
For additional information, please refer to the [Chapter Error Handling in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php)

Comment: Except PHP cannot log anything if there was a fatal error.

Answer (score 63):

Simply put these codes at top of your PHP/index file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // Error/Exception engine, always use E_ALL

ini_set('ignore_repeated_errors', TRUE); // always use TRUE

ini_set('display_errors', FALSE); // Error/Exception display, use FALSE only in production environment or real server. Use TRUE in development environment

ini_set('log_errors', TRUE); // Error/Exception file logging engine.
ini_set('error_log', 'your/path/to/errors.log'); // Logging file path
```

Comment: That's only if you *also* want all errors to be displayed in output and/or to the browser, *in addition* to logging.  `display_errors` should NEVER be turned on on a live production server -- that directive is specifically for output to the user, and has no effect on logging. http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display_errors

Answer (score 26):

Add this code in file *.htaccess* (as an alternative to file *php.ini* or the *ini_set* function):

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag log_errors on 
php_value error_log ./path_to_MY_PHP_ERRORS.log
# php_flag display_errors on 
</IfModule>
```

- as commented: this is for **Apache**-type servers, and not for **[Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx)** or others.

Comment: This is very specifically to do with Apache's PHP module, however.

Answer (score 16):

That's my personal short function

```
# logging
/*
[2017-03-20 3:35:43] [INFO] [file.php] Here we are
[2017-03-20 3:35:43] [ERROR] [file.php] Not good
[2017-03-20 3:35:43] [DEBUG] [file.php] Regex empty

mylog ('hallo') -> INFO
mylog ('fail', 'e') -> ERROR
mylog ('next', 'd') -> DEBUG
mylog ('next', 'd', 'debug.log') -> DEBUG file debug.log
*/
function mylog($text, $level='i', $file='logs') {
    switch (strtolower($level)) {
        case 'e':
        case 'error':
            $level='ERROR';
            break;
        case 'i':
        case 'info':
            $level='INFO';
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'debug':
            $level='DEBUG';
            break;
        default:
            $level='INFO';
    }
    error_log(date("[Y-m-d H:i:s]")."\t[".$level."]\t[".basename(__FILE__)."]\t".$text."\n", 3, $file);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44745716/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Kinda intense, @PeterMortensen :D Really intense.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [`log_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) configuration option in php.ini. It seems to do just what you want to. I think you can use the [`error_log`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) option to set your own logging file too.

When the `log_errors` directive is set to `On`, any errors reported by PHP would be logged to the server log or the file specified with `error_log`. You can set these options with [`ini_set`](http://php.net/ini_set) too, if you need to.

(Please note that `display_errors` should be disabled in php.ini if this option is enabled)

Comment: Why should `display_errors` be disabled if you enable `log_errors`? Doesn't make sense in my opinion. :)

Comment: Because there's no need to output the content of the errors to the public on a production server, especially if the text of the error is being discreetly logged into a file.

Comment: Display errors should be always disabled on production server. Not if error logging is configured to somewhere else, but always. Errors are logged to apache error log by default, that is often enough.

Comment: Displaying errors on production makes PHP more popular :)

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers mention the importance or relevance to Agile teams; professional-level development work is more often than not done within the context of a squad.

Keeping in mind that many development teams use a task-tracking tool such as `JIRA`, I prefer to use a timestamp to log each error as a separate file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/logs/php/php-errors-' . time() . '.txt');
```

Using this approach, it is easy for a Project Manager or Team Lead to then isolate each error as a specific file that can then be attached to a unique JIRA defect, assigned to a developer, and tracked (the timestamp can be linked within the defect to easily track while the defect fix is In-Progress). When the issue is closed, then the file can be deleted from the log directory, while a copy of it (if needed for future reference) can be accessed in the JIRA.

Answer (score -1):

In addition, you need the "AllowOverride Options" directive for this to work. (Apache 2.2.15)

Answer (score -2):

here's my log function:

You can edit the log rows by editing `$maxLogs=5`,
also the order to write your logs `$logOrder='top'`

```
<?php
lg('script start','start');

#Code......
lg('script end','End of code');

function lg($str,$mod='Your Log Category'){
    $ts = microtime(true);
    if(!defined('logTimer')){
        define('logTimer',microtime(true));
    }
    $diff=abs(round(($ts-logTimer)*1000,2));
    $maxLogs=5;
    $logOrder='top';#new Logs at top
    
    
    $filename = './log.txt';
    $log=[];
    if(!file_exists($filename)){
        if(!file_put_contents($filename,json_encode($log,128))){
            echo "Can’t open to write '$filename' Check Permissions";
            return;
        }
    }else{
        $c=file_get_contents($filename);
        if(trim($c)==''){$c='[]';}
        
        $log =@json_decode($c,true);
        if(!is_Array($log)){$log=[];}
    }
    $new=['mod'=>$mod,'date'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." Scripttime: ".$diff."ms",'log'=>$str];
    if($logOrder=='top'){
        array_unshift($log , $new);
        $log=array_slice($log,0,$maxLogs);
        }else{
        $log[]=$new;
        $log=array_slice($log,0-$maxLogs,$maxLogs);
    }
    
    
    $logs=json_encode($log,128);
    if(!file_put_contents($filename,$logs) ){echo ("Can’t open to write '$filename' Check Permissions") ;return;}
    return $str;
}
?>
```

The Output looks like:

```
[
    {
        "mod": "delete",
        "date": "2022-08-04 13:48:02 0.33ms",
        "log": "test 2"
    },
    {
        "mod": "start",
        "date": "2022-08-04 13:48:29 0ms",
        "log": "test"
    },
    {
        "mod": "delete",
        "date": "2022-08-04 13:48:29 0.27ms",
        "log": "test 2"
    },
    {
        "mod": "start",
        "date": "2022-08-04 13:48:34 0ms",
        "log": "test"
    },
    {
        "mod": "delete",
        "date": "2022-08-04 13:48:34 0.92ms",
        "log": "test 2"
    }
]
```

Comment: `echo "Can’t open to write '$filename' Check Permissions";`? For a function that's intended to log errors?  *Seriously?*

Comment: Also, read up on the race condition. You'll have your file deleted in no time on a live server. Let alone performance issues. In your place I'd leave this code alone and look at the accepted answer.