# Wordpress suppressing php error through htaccess throwing 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am suppressing PHP errors from the front-end through `.htaccess` in WordPress. I want to hide the errors thrown by WordPress if we are trying to access a file through folder structure:

**eg:** `www.my_site/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/sidebar-page.php`

**.htaccess snippet:**

```
php_flag display_errors off
```

But, it is showing a 500 internal server error. I've tried

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

in the header.php file, no change.
Is there any way to redirect to the homepage if a 500 error occurs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php hide ALL errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242903/php-hide-all-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
```

That should cause any 500 error to redirect to the home page. The header will still have a 500 status, so it would be interesting to see how WordPress handles that.

Comment: Fresh eyes on this: ErrorDocument handling tells apache what file to open when an error appears, it will not redirect. But if you put /index.php it should start the WordPress process and when WordPress's permalink logic grabs the path, it will not find a match and respond with the theme's 404.