# disable MySql errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

Is there any way to prevent MySql errors (if happened) from appearing to the client, and just log them somewhere ?

**Note 1:
Am not using any frameworks, just native PHP with PDO extinsion and MySql.**

**Note 2:
This code will stop PHP errors, not MySql.**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 0);
error_reporting(0);
```

Example:

disabling errors like

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ..
```

Comment: Use @ and errors will not show up but you should prevent errors from happening

Comment: That will only display if you `echo mysqli_connect_error($link);`, so don't do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php hide ALL errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242903/php-hide-all-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-PHP errors, the application (programmer) is responsible for obtaining and displaying/logging the error.  So for your specific example, don't display it, log it:

```
//instead of displaying
if (!$link) {
    die(mysqli_connect_error());
}

//log it
if (!$link) {
    error_log(mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

You could also us [trigger_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) that would respect your error reporting settings:

```
if (!$link) {
    trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: So in the case of PDO there is "PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE", but i notice  that give it PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT value still show sql errors when happens ..
is there a way to stop it ?

Comment: `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` is default and does not display, you would need to set `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` or `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` to have it display something. Somwhere the code is either displaying the error or telling PHP to generate one.

Comment: Yes, i found that I'm printing the error in try catch with getMessage() method.
Thank you !