# Way to automatically send mysql errors and other errors to log file?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, web-hosting

I have some `PHP` pages on a web host that perform some data access with a `MySQL` database.

Is there likely to be a setting somewhere in either the `PHP` or `MySQl` administration that will cause any errors, particularly `MySQL` errors, to be automatically logged to a file somewhere accessible to me as a customer of the web-host?

Alternatively, can I put something at the top of each `PHP` page that will achieve the same thing?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file

Answer (score 1):

The long answer is to check for error at each MySQL action you perform

Example:

```
mysql_select_db($dbname)
or log_error(mysql_error());
```

The *hacky* way is to use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to capture PHP errors when they would appear on the page.

Comment: I see that you are using a lazy-OR to cause the `log_error` to execute if the `mysql_select` fails. Is it possible for a PHP installation to have been configured not to do lazy-ORs?

Comment: I don't think so, it's kind of a shorthand for 
`if(!mysql_select_db($dbname)) log_error(mysql_error());`