# Internal server error, and errordocument

Tags: php

in my site if I try to go by link to file php (only in this link,other works fine)appear this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete    
your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@****.com and inform them of 
the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the   
error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an  
ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: psychic....abilities...failing me....

Comment: This is a giveaway: `More information about this error may be available in the server error log.` They want you to *read* the error log. We too. Don't you? (;

Comment: I'm sorry,where can I find the server error log?

Comment: @Kami pointed it out, in [this SO question](stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703) there's more info.

Comment: I'm working on remote server by ftp...can I find the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable PHP error logging to a log file - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531852/1603275.

Then review the details to identify the source of the error.