# session destroyed on page reload or redirect

Tags: php, session, session-variables

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login']=1;
```

I tried this with cookies, and also tried on different servers.
The code working on local but not on live servers.
What causes the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: A warning message was shown there thats why i added session_save_path('/tmp'); session_start();$_SESSION['login']=1; code instead of above.

Comment: Make sure temp path is writable.

Comment: My problem is that session is destroying by itself

Comment: yea i wrote it.session_save_path('/tmp');

Comment: I want to say that make sure your temp path has write permission.

Comment: when i login session is set.. and if i reload it or redirecting to another page, session is destroying

Comment: Ok Ravi could you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: how to check temp path permission

Comment: @sumandeepkaur: Check my answer. Which os are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your temp path has write permission.

In your file, write below lines to check session is set or not.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && !empty($_SESSION['login'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['login'];
}else{
   echo 'session not set';
}
```

**Note**:- You need to call `session_start()` on all your pages.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Yes once session is set.. values appear.but on reload or redirect values destroyed.

Comment: You need to call session_start() on all your pages.

Comment: it is calling on each and every page .

Comment: I have been trying it for many days..but not getting what the issue is. Please solve it, if possible. Will be grateful to u

Comment: check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879200/session-is-destroyed-on-page-refresh-in-php

Comment: Yea i tried above code it shows Set and not empty.But if i try to echo $_SESSION[YOUR_SESSION_NAME] , it comes empty.

Comment: Using this code i have solved my problem <?php session_save_path('/tmp'); ?> thanks for helping me.