# How to write PHP errors to stderr?

Tags: logging, stdout, php, stderr

How can I change php-fpm.conf (or php.ini) so all errors/ warnings/ ... are written to stderr (or alternatively to stdout)?

I run `php5-fpm` with `daemonize = no` and want to see all errors in my terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to set ...

```
; Redirect worker stdout and stderr into main error log. If not set, stdout and
; stderr will be redirected to /dev/null according to FastCGI specs.
; Note: on highloaded environement, this can cause some delay in the page
; process time (several ms).
; Default Value: no
catch_workers_output = yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible without messing with the .ini config.

---

Use a [Unix descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), like one of those example:

```
php myscript.php 2> errors.log
```

Or by using a hashbang, file must then be set as executable:

```
./myscript 2> errors.log
```

From there all errors will be logged.

---

To write only in `errors.log`, use `fwrite` anywhere in your php script:

```
<?php
fwrite(STDERR, "Some debug infos\n");
```

Appear only in `errors.log`. Useful when writing fast refreshing scripts.

Notice that all errors are erased when restarting.

---

To watch for errors, use `tail -f` or `watch cat`

```
watch cat errors.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can achieve that, at least in the way I am understanting it from your question.

I wiil propose you a work around to view php through terminal in real time

**Step 1** - write all error to a file

change your php.ini file to write every error to file `/logs/phpLogs`

**Step 2** - via error 'real time' using [tail](http://ss64.com/bash/tail.html)

From your command line run the tail command
`tail -f /logs/phpLogs`

**Step 3** - Optionally use [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

User the php error_log command
`error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true ))`

**EDIT** : (just found it) My anwser is similar to that [How to log errors and warnings into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file)