# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library Cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a site hosted on a shared server and I use CPANEL to upload the files and do minor configurations, this means I do not have access to the root folders.  The uploaded site is up, then it goes down for a reason I am not sure of.

The following is the error I saw on the error log file:

> [27-Oct-2014 08:16:16 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I have been searching the net, but I don't really get what I am looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by site going down? Can you elaborate? What error do you get while you access your website?

Comment: If you're on a shared server, you should talk to your server administer/hosting provider about this.

Comment: @Searock When I ping the domain the url wouldnt resolve at times

Comment: @kya You didn't reply to my answer. Do you get any errors while visiting your website from the browser? Or do you get a blank white page? How often do you face this problem? Try logging the errors into a file. `ini_set("log_errors", 1);` `ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");` Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3531852/92487

Comment: I get a "Page not found" Message as if the site is down. but when saw this error in the error log page that was created by cpanel

Comment: I cant do much from my site.

Comment: Have you added the code and checked php-error.log log file?

Answer (score -2):

I can see ImageMagick in not installed on your server and due to that you are getting this issues. Please try to install it with

```
yum install ImageMagick-devel ImageMagick-c++-devel ImageMagick-perl
```

Comment: The OP has stated that he has a shared server and have also mentioned that he does not have root access.

Comment: Nice answer, but I don't have access to root and terminal.

Comment: You will have to discuss this with your hosting provider. They will install imagick on your server OR correct imagick.so path if imagick is already installed on the server.

Comment: Wrong reply. You answer by quickly, and your reply it's not good process for Cpanel serever. if you has not ImageMagick-devel, that it's not problem. Sys admin must be re-run Easyapache for correct problem with libraries COMPILED with old PHP version.