# log_errors and error_log in php for php.ini

Tags: php, ini, error-log

I'm troing to change settings in php.ini throu php. My problem is that when there is an error, its not put in to the file error_log.txt, so what am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
// Settings for php.ini
ini_set("session.cookie_httponly", 1);
ini_set("session.cookie_secure", 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
error_reporting(0);

// errormeddelanden loggas i logs/errorlog.txt 
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/logs/error_log.txt');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the function `error_log()`.

A simple example  from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file) would be like

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
error_log( "Hello, errors!" );
```

Then check the log file .you cold see like

```
tail -f /tmp/php-error.log
```

Comment: Yes I have seen that, but I have a friend who only has this code and he gets the errors in to the log file. That is what I want to do. I cant find in his code that he uses error_log("error message"); I Want all errors on the site to go into that file, not just where I put error_log(); I Can't find what I'm doing different to him either..

Comment: It worked with changing ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/logs/error_log.txt'); to ini_set("error_log", "/logs/error_log.txt");  I din't need to use the last code =).

Comment: @SannaBergström wow ..am glad that it helped ...:) happy coding