# NSUrl using stringwithformat to pass data to php page always returns sent value as zero

Tags: php, objective-c, nsurl, stringwithformat

This is the objective-c code

```
NSString *CategoryID = @"2";
NSString *strURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://****/iCategoryItems.php?CategoryID=%@",CategoryID];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And this is the php code of the icategoryitems.php page

```
$cid = $GET_["CategoryID"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items where cat_id = '".$cid."' ";
```

however the code as-is always returns the items with cat_id = 0

Am I sending categoryID wrong way, or reading it from the php wrong way !

Comment: First step you need to do is to enable error reporting and logging. Then set the error level to the highest level and get your code warning and notices free: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3531703/367456 - Then there is even another website to go to first: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
$cid = $_GET["CategoryID"];
       ^^^
```

Your code is wiiiide open to sql injection attacks as well. You should be using PDO for your queries: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: WOW, i can't believe i didn't notice that !!! Thanks, and i will check out PDO ... thx