# Create server log

Tags: php

I am working on a rather large website and i need to log errors that users may face while using the website.

**Here is how it will work:**

```
>if operation passed
     #operation success
>else
     #Log the failure
```

**log()**

```
>email admin
>create log
```

What i need to know is the best practice for creating this log, because there are several methods for doing this.

```
text based
database
```

There is possibly a better method for doing this as well, which is why i'm asking stack overflow.

Just tell me how you would go about doing this, and i will do the rest of the research and coding on my own.

Comment: there are several opensource logging frame works. A quick search would find them: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341154/php-logging-framework

Comment: Apache actually logs all your errors for you in `/var/log/apache2`. It's called `error.log` I believe.

Comment: @MitchWheat I am writing production based code, not beta. Oh and huey sorry, i should have mentioned its not debug errors its 'my own conditions that i flag'.

Comment: erm , what?....There's no difference. Unless you are talking about Auditing rather than error logging. "i need to log errors that users may face while using the website."

Comment: perhaps, i am. I am only logging when a conditions are met (and they aren't suppose to be met)

Answer (score 0):

I find using a 3rd party service like airbrake.io or pagerduty.com is best. Basically, they handle creating a ticket and logging everything as well as notifying the proper people about the incident. Yes, you can write up your own system the way you mention via emailing an admin and creating your own logs... but then you will also have to worry about updating the email list and emailing the right people at the right time... What if you're on vacation? Who is to get the email at that point? 3rd party services manage all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (and probably should use) open source logging frameworks for the language you are working in. They will provide you with nice wrappers for all your logging needs, most have the option to email logs to you (and even upload files to remote directories).

If you wish to create your own logging system, this is how I would personally do it:

- Make a `log` directory
- Create a log file (plain text) each hour (or day or X units of time) using a naming scheme
- Write 1 line to the file with the time, then some delimiter, then the error (including error codes/messages etc)

Every time an hour or day passes, you would make a new file and email the previous file to yourself (or admin). You can also send an immediate email for fatal errors/issues. I wouldn't really use a database personally.

I implemented such a logging system for a online script that talks to a gaming server. The end result is a directory of files filled with logs for each hour of each day. Files older than 30 days are also deleted. It allows me to check on how things are going easily and pinpoint certain events/issues that players on the game server experience. However, I only wrote my own logger as there was no script that did this for my game.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since it was mentioned in the comments, we should differntiate the php error log from a custom application log:

The php error log logs errors of a certain level (notices, errors, warnings depending on your error_reporting() settings) while interpreting your php files. That means when you are trying to use an array key which was not set before a warning would be generated and either printed to the screen or logged to your php error log file.

A custom application logger on the other side logs custom messages which might contain warnings and errors regarding the application logic and which are able to be handled by the application.

When we compare the following two code examples:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', sys_get_temp_dir() . '/php_error.log');

updateUser($_POST['user_id']);

// Assuming $_POST['user_id'] was not set the above lines would produce a notice in your php_error.log stating the use of an undefined index 'user_id'

?>
```

Against:

```
// Instantiate your own logger or a 3rd party logger
$myLogger = new Logger(sys_get_temp_dir() . '/application.log');

if (!array_key_exists('user_id', $_POST)) {

    $myLogger->error('Cannot update user since user_id was not set');

    // Handle the error in the UI accordingly
    header('Location: 404.php');
    die();

}

updateUser($_POST['user_id']);

?>
```

For me personally it makes sense to separate these two types of errors in different log files: The php errors are usually a result of code which does not handle all imaginable cases (i.e. a user removes the hidden user_id field from a form manually) and are a hint for yourself that you should change your code to avoid the same error next time.
The second piece of code handles the exactly same use case but you considered this case while writing the code and the application is able to react somehow.

No matter if you decide pick a 3rd party logger or write your own: Think about using one which fulfils the [PRS-3 logging standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/) to be able to make it exchangable when you i.e. decide to switch from file based logging to a database based logging mechanism. By doing so you won't have to change a lot of code when you decide to switch your loggers since the methods and general usage is standardised.

When writing your own logger, consider the following points:

- Locking and unlocking your log file while writing to it
- Log rotation (daily, weekly, monthly)
- Deletion of old log files
- Like stated above think about implementing PSR-3