# PHP errors not being displayed although they are "on" in the php.ini file

Tags: php

I am on OpenSUSE, I've installed PHP, when I test a simple PHP code, it works, but once I'm trying to display a PHP code that has errors, I get the following error :

**The localhost page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**

I have changed the value of **display_errors** to **on** in the *php.ini* file, I have also tried all solutions I could find but I still do get that message instead of the actual errors in my PHP file.

I have also added the following lines on the beginning of my PHP file but it didn't solve the problem :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
```

Comment: **Related**: Take a look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: Please include your code to be able to evaluate your problem. Also considering turning on your apache server as error is related to server.

Comment: Why not using a log file in this case? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file)

Comment: @CanB I am using a log file, but I want them to be displayed in the browser instead.

Comment: @ShyamBhimani My question wasn't about the errors in my code, I am having issues in displaying them, if I write the following code in a file : <?php echo 'test' ?> I won't get an error saying that a comma is missing but I'll get that error I mentioned above instead, scripts with no errors work fine.

Comment: What IDE are you using ?

Comment: @ShyamBhimani I am using Komodo Edit 10