# Edit php.ini to log errors to different file then default

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to store error logs to different file than default `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

I tried editing php.ini with: 
`error_log = /home/username/public_html/php_errors.log`

and it was there already:
`log_errors = On`

but still logs keep saving into default file.

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right `ini`?

Comment: You might have two php.ini files, one for cli and one for apache.

Comment: `phpinfo();` will tell you if your editing the right file

Comment: Have you restarted your web server's?

Comment: Also check permissions - both for directory and selinux

Comment: I was editing `ini` in cli, now I edited the one in apache dir too and still nothing. I also tried restarting web server. @chirs85 @aconnelly @JohnZ
On my dir I have username on permission and on `php_errors.log` I have `web-data` premission @YounElan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log errors and warnings into a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file)