# Data not inserted in the database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

EDIT TO CORRECT THE LINE `echo "Error: " + $e->getMessage;`.

I am trying to make a simple example just to add data from a form and with PHP upload the data to the database.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rich Text</title>
    <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        plugins: "link"
    });</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="formulario" action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>Inserta título</p>
        <textarea name="texto" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And PHP code:

```
<?php

try {
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host;localhost=Blog', 'root', '' );
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage;
}

if (isset($_POST['enviar']) and $conexion) {
   $texto = $_POST['texto'];
   echo $texto;

   $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO art (ID, articulo) VALUES     (NULL, $texto)");
   $statement->execute();
}

require 'index.view.php';

?>
```

Is it necessary to specify the ID column as it is autoincrement?

Comment: No, you only insert the columns necessary. You may want to turn on error reporting in your page to see what the issue is if that doesn't work. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the data at all.

Comment: this is **NOT** how you are meant to use Prepared statements. Your script is set out using prepared statements but your line involving the SQL and the `$texto` var is undoing all that good promise. [learn how to use prepared statements properly](http://prash.me/php-pdo-and-prepared-statements).

Comment: Your variable `$texto` is unquoted in the query. That is a syntax error. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql) to correct it as is. But more importantly, you should be using a named parameter. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php#60496) for examples on how to do it correctly, which will solve this issue.

Comment: All of the above. But the very first problem is probably the dsn, that looks really off as well. The `mysql:host;localhost=Blog` part that is.

Comment: Thanks to all. Finally I solve the problem thanks specially to @MichaelBerkowski answer. The other two problems in the code were my fault.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

`$statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO art (ID, articulo) VALUES (NULL, $texto)");`

To this:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO art (articulo) VALUES (:texto)"); 
$statement->bindParam(':texto', $texto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

You do not need to specify columns you don't change, such as your auto-increment column (`ID`). This column will look after itself.

Using `BindParam` is one of the correct ways of inserting data ***safely*** into your database.

Comment: Should note that `BindParam` is not the *only* correct way ;)

Comment: If you have further issues you should  use [PHP Error logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file) to find and identify your problems

Comment: @JetLagFox Why do you used "$_POST['enviar']"? I think that "$_POST['texto']" is the right way here...

Comment: @DiegoMedeiros is to check if it has been send something (submit button).

Answer (score 0):

See [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

You can't concatenate strings in php with + symbol, you may use . to concatenate

```
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage;
```

To connect to a database you should use

```
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Blog", root, '');
```

You don't need to insert ID if you configured your table to autoincrement.

Comment: Er, you're incorrect here. you can happily pass `NULL` to an auto-increment field in MySQL

Comment: You are right, I have edited the code because that has been a mistake as I am studying java...my fault. I have changed the conexion code, but I keeps not working.