# How to log errors on hosting that does not support logs?

Tags: php, logging

I want to log errors to a file using this method:

```
$tpath = "/storage/my-errors.log";
error_log("You messed up!", 3, $tpath);
```

I have set permissions on the path to `777` and it should save this value `"You messed up!"` into the file, but I can't figure it out.

I made an error myself, but it did not get saved in the log file, just messaged `"You messed up!"`!

I also tried:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "mypath");
error_log( "Hello, errors!" );
```

Comment: So do you want to throw an error? Or what exactly is it that you are asking?

Comment: @DavidWolters i want to log php and mysql errors if they exit

Comment: The path that you see as `/storage` is most likely not just `/storage` but something like `/users/i/n/g/ingus/storage/` or similar with your username. You can likely figure it out by dumping the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable. Chances are you don't have write to anything above your own personal directory but they have chroot'ed (or locked the ftp) above that so you see `/` as your root when it really isn't the root of the server.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn i just added it short i have the full path and as i sayed that message is inserting in my log file.its just that i cant add php/mysql errors in it

Comment: If you just need to direct normal PHP errors to your specific log, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file

Comment: how about: `ini_set("log_errors","1");
ini_set("error_log","/path/to/file/errors.txt");`

Comment: If you have access to create your php.ini (some hosts do allow) or setup an htaccess file you can also set all of those directives (from Don't Panic's comment) there which would allow you to capture fatal and syntax errors.

Comment: This looks like it _might_ be a duplicate of that, but I haven't voted to close because I'm not totally sure if you're asking the same thing.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i thin that could be duplicate also i saw that post before but there nothing helped me :( the last straw was to post new message :(

Comment: My main point is, `error_log` will log an error (either to a specified log or the server's default), but specifying a log path in a call to `error_log` doesn't set the log path for general PHP errors, only for that specific call. To direct other errors to your custom path, you'll need to use one of the various ini methods, whether it's `ini_set`, or one of the other possibilities that Jonathan mentioned.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you use `ini_set`, it will change the setting only during execution of the script (not permanently), so you'll have to be sure to call it with every request.

Comment: ok going to try to do it ASAP thanks guys!

Comment: cant make it work :( ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/storage/my-errors.log");
error_log( "Hello, errors!" );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log using your desired method into a CSV.

Create a re-usable function which will control all your logging:

```
function logger($log_name, $log_message){

  $todays_date = date('Y-m-d');

  // Open the file to write to it, file is created if it does not exist.
  $output = fopen($log_name."-".$todays_date.".csv", 'w');

  // Write line of log in CSV format to the log.
  fputcsv($output, array("[".$todays_date."] ",$log_message));

  // Close the file.
  fclose($output);
}
```

You can use this with your process names as the $log_name.

**Example**

```
logger("user_login", "You messed up");
```

This would produce a log called `user_login-2017-02-13.csv`. The file will be created if it does not exist, and subsequent writes to the file will be appended line by line.

The date part is there to automatically make a new file for each day, so you can alter that to your needs.

Comment: This is really cool !Thanks!But i want to lop php/mysql errors as i have no accses to them