# MYSQL UPDATE ERROR - UNABLE TO FIND ISSUE

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error:

> Update Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ContactOfficeNo='20045878' WHERE ClientCode='MARI'' at line 2

Now I notice after `ClientCode='Mari'`, there is another `'?`

But my code is as below. I can't seem to find the issue. I've got opening & closing `""` with the update query inside as it should be:

```
include("../dbinfo.inc.php");
$comm=@mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
$rs=@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 

$id = $_POST["clientcode"];
$cli = $_POST["clientname"];
$em1 = $_POST["email1"];
$em2 = $_POST["email2"];
$em3 = $_POST["email3"];
$cry = $_POST["currency"];
$occ = $_POST["othercc"];
$mob = $_POST["mobile"];
$dty = $_POST["dtymobile"];
$off = $_POST["office"];

$sql = "UPDATE tbl_client SET ClientName='$cli', ContactEmail#1='$em1', ContactEmail#2='$em2', ContactEmail#3='$em3', Currency='$cry', OtherCCinfo='$occ', ContactMobileNo='$mob', DutyMobileNo='$dty', 
ContactOfficeNo='$off' WHERE ClientCode='$id'";
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: If you use parameterized queries, you won't have this problem.

Comment: I have edited the code, this is parameterized is it not? The issue im having is strange to me, because i have the exact same format for another table, which works perfectly fine, yet im having this error

Comment: This is not parameterized queries. For that, you need to use MySQLi or PDO (which you really should switch to, `mysql_*` is old and insecure), and prepare your queries with the `prepare()` method and use placeholders in your query instead of directly injecting the variables.

Comment: No, it's not a parameterized query.  You can't do those using the old deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions

Comment: `ContactEmail#1`?!? You really have a `#` in your column names? `Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers: ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore) Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF` If you have other characters, then you need to wrap the column name in backticks (`\``)

Comment: @MarkBaker I thought the same thing on first impression but if the error message refers to a later column in the SQL I can only assume that `#` are infact acceptable in this particular breed of setup..... else the error would relate to earlier columns, any of them..... (?)

Comment: @Martin [MySQL Docs reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)... though you're right that the error message isn't highlighting this directly

Comment: @MarkBaker I would have expected an error feedback for column  `ContactEmail#1` rather than the later column. I do realise that you are correct, it's just odd that this issue is somehow not the one the OP is writing about...

Comment: I've placed the code on a single line, and the error being outputted now is **right syntax to use near '' at line 1**

Comment: @CS88 read my answer, do what is outlined in my answer, then edit your question with the additional details from point 1 and 2, or magically discover your question solved by following points 3-7. `:-)`

Comment: @MarkBaker I've referenced your comment and your doc reference to my answer.

Comment: There is no need to shout, @CS88. Would you replace the title with the sentence case equivalent please?

Comment: @MarkBaker you were right, Changed the cols in phpmyadmin to remove the '#' from each of the emails and its appeared to do the trick.. Not sure as to why the error was pointing to the " at the end of the query..

Comment: Potentially the newline in your code; `#` starts comment in an SQL statement until the end of the current line... if that is treated as a comment, it will read as `UPDATE tbl_client SET ClientName='$cli', ContactEmail 
ContactOfficeNo='$off' WHERE ClientCode='$id'`, which is invalid SQL, and would highlight the point of error that you got

Comment: However, editing your question has now made it meaningless and unhelpful to anybody else that might encounter a similar problem... I've rolled it back again so that it may help others

Comment: Great, thanks Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the value of `$dty` ? It is useful in these moments to remember two tips:

- ) The error (almost) always occurs before the "near" point in the SQL error output notice, so the few characters **BEFORE** `ContactOfficeNo='20045878` is whatever is causing your issue.
- ) It is good practive to [error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file) out your complete SQL before you run it to see exactly what's going on when the error occurs.

  ```
  error_log("My SQL: Line ".__LINE__." :". $sql );
  ```

---

**Additionals:**

1) As others comments have said you really, REALLY should be looking at using MySQLi or PDO Parameterised queries.

> [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says *[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*. Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

-- Jay Blanchard

> If you use parameterized queries, you won't have this problem.

-- Gordon Linoff

2) Stop using `@` to suppress errors. You're causing yourself more problems than you're solving.

3) MySQL is ***DEPRECATED*** and should not be used. Use `MySQLi` (or `PDO`). **NOW**.

4) Please read and take heed of the comments by Gordon and Jay underneath your question, this is (probably) the cause of your issue, you're not escaping your `$_POST` input. This is extremely dangerous and will (is) causing you all sorts of issues and bumps.

5) Having non alphabetic characters (so not a-z) in your MySQL column name is risky at best, and may be causing you additional issues. Highly recommended to move away from having any non-a-z characters in your column names.

Please read the [docs refrence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) by Mark Baker about suitable column names.

> `ContactEmail#1`?!? You really have a # in your column names? `Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers: ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore) Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF` If you have other characters, then you need to wrap the column name in backticks (`)

-- Mark Baker

Comment: Answers are better if they incorporate what somewhat said, rather than asking the reader to read a comment elsewhere. The main reason for this is that comments may be deleted, which would make this answer harder to understand if that happens in this case. You can either quote someone verbatim (e.g. with a quote block) or you can just take the essence of what they said and merge it into your answer.

Comment: +10. And if there's some (unfathomable) reason that it's not possible to use a prepared statement with bind placeholders, then at a bare minimum, potentially unsafe values included in SQL text must be properly escaped. (Consider e.g. what happens when the value passed in for `clientcode` is "**`1' OR 1=1 --`**