# how to write all error_logs in only a file in php

Tags: php, error-handling

Hi i not have access to php.ini and i use this post [How to log errors and warnings into a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file)

i have 23 file and 47 sub directory in public_html

i want Anywhere happening error or warning all errors write in public_html/my_error.log

but now i have in any sub directory a error.log file

i try this code but this only change name log erors files in public_html and sub directory

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag log_errors on 
php_value error_log ./path_to_MY_PHP_ERRORS.log
</IfModule>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i not have access to php.ini

The [`error_log` ini directive is writable from everywhere](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log), so you dont need access to the ini file itself. You can just set it with [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), e.g.

```
ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/your/error.log");
```

> but now i have in any sub directory a error.log file

If you have a log file in every subdirectory you likely specified a [relative path instead of an absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) for the destination argument in `[error_log()][1]`. Mind the example:

```
error_log("You messed up!", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
```

Likewise, in the httpd configuration snippet, use an absolute path:

```
php_value error_log /absolute/path_to_MY_PHP_ERRORS.log
```