# Add PHP generated errors in error log

Tags: php

I have this code here to create error log:

```
  error_log(date("[Y-m-d H:i:s]:")." You messed up!", 3, "../my-errors.log");
```

Here, we can see the custom error '**You messed up!**' that I have set to print in the error log. I don't want to use the custom error here. Instead of this I want to set the Errors/Warnings/Notices that are generated by PHP itself.

Is this possible and how can we do that?

Thankyou

Comment: If you want to log PHP's regular errors / warnings, then just enable php logging. They are already probably being logged to a directory like /var/log/apache/error.log. Or just change the directory if you want to log it to a custom file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file

Answer (score 1):

if I understood it well, you're looking for [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php):

> **array error_get_last ( void )**
>
> error_get_last — Get the last occurred error. /  Gets information about the last error that occurred.

Take a look:

```
$last_error = error_get_last();
$formated_last_error = sprintf('%s in %s on line %d'.PHP_EOL, 
   $last_error['message'], $last_error['file'], $last_error['line']);

error_log(date(DATE_ATOM) . $formated_last_error().PHP_EOL, 3, '/tmp/logs.log');
```

However, you should take a look at [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function which is a general approach.