# How to configure new line behavior in apache error.log for nicely displaying arrays

Tags: php, arrays, apache, newline

My Apache writes a new line as `\\n` to the apache error.log, so that in the console I get this output:

```
[Wed Feb 28 01:06:04.777718 2018] [:error] Mooc\\DB\\Block Object\n(\n    [errors] => Array\n        (\n        )\n\n    [content:protected] => Array\n        (\n        )\n\n    [content_db:protected] => Array\n        (\n
```

How is the error.log configured, for getting this output:

```
[Wed Feb 28 01:06:04.777718 2018] [:error]  Mooc\\DB\\Block Object(
[errors] => Array
    (
    )

[content:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[content_db:protected] => Array
    (
```

Comment: try to use a custom error log file. See, for example, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file).

Comment: Thanks, that works, but isn't there a way to get that in the default apache error.log???