# How to log errors for specific script to a file?

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to save all script errors in a txt file, I know that there is a function to change the log file:

```
ini_set("error_log", "file path");
```

Is that function changing the error_log path in the php.ini?

Or it just log that PHP file errors to a specific file rather that the error_log file?

So for example if I have a file called 'file.php' and that file contains some PHP code, If an error occurs there it's saved to that custom files.

But for other PHP files, When an error occurs, It's saved to the default error_log file.

How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried it? Is this some way of trying to tell us that you tried using `ini_set("error_log", "...")` and it didn't work? Have you tried googling? 100% duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log errors and warnings into a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file)

Comment: Must be hard to try it and see what happens

Comment: @Xatenev, I viewed that question twice, It's not answering my question

Comment: I googled my question and that question appeared , Before asking that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PHP's built-in function error_log():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

It will give you a variety of options including the one you are after.

Comment: Yes but that's if I have the error message stored in a variable

Comment: If you cannot trap the errors programmatically then your original idea should work using ini_set() which is changing PHP configuration variables at runtime. After script execution, the original value in php.ini is preserved.

Comment: Try ensuring the log file has write permissions?