# Write PHP script output in a txt file

Tags: php, error-handling

I want a way to write the errors and warnings in `PHP` script or the output of the script for example echo "Hello World"; in Text File
I don't think `error_log()` function is useful in my case because this function is logging the errors that I previously mentioned in my code.

What I want is something like this
**PHP Code**

```
<?php

echo "Your Name is ".$name; // $name here is not defined 

?>
```

This script will give the following error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp64\www\example.php on line 3
```

This error will be written in php_error.log automatically in my server, but  I want to write this error in separated text file.

Comment: See [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog).

Comment: You can set a destination file in `error_log()`. You can also set a different file in php.ini.

Comment: Check answers of this.question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-do-i-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file

Comment: @Talk2Nit This question does not answer my question. Check the example i give in the question and understand what I want to log into the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom error handler that you set with the [`set_error_handler`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function

```
<?php

function handleError($errorNumber, $errorString, $errorFile, $errorLine, array $errContext)
{
    // Path to log file
    $logFilePath = 'errors.log';

    // Do we want to prevent the default PHP error handler from executing?
    $allowDefaultLogging = true;

    // error was suppressed with the @-operator do not log and cancel the default error handler
    if (0 === error_reporting())
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Build log message string from error components
    $message = $errorFile . ':' . $errorLine . ' errno ' . $errorNumber . ' ' . $errorString . PHP_EOL;

    // Open the file for writing, append, create file if it does not exist
    $logHandle = fopen($logFilePath, 'a+');

    // Write the error message
    fwrite($logHandle, $message);

    // Close the file handle
    fclose($logHandle);

    // Tell PHP whether or not to handle the error with the default handler
    return $allowDefaultLogging;
}

// Tell PHP we want errors to go to our custom handler
set_error_handler('handleError');

echo "Your Name is " . $name . PHP_EOL; // $name here is not defined
```